# CakePHP help in blog tutorial - Simple Authentication and Authorization Application Last Part

Tags: php, cakephp, authentication, cakephp-2.0

In the Blog Tutorial on Cakephp 2.0 in the Simple Authentication and Authorization Section there is a code block in the last part that I can't understand
what does this line do?

```
// app/Model/Post.php

public function isOwnedBy($post, $user) {
    return $this->field('id', array('id' => $post, 'user_id' => $user)) === $post;
}
```

I hope anyone can help me into this.

Comment: Judging from the filename and the method's name I think it is safe to say that it checks whether a post *is owned by* (or *was created by*) a particular user. In order to understand what it does you need to look at what the arguments `$post` and `$user` are, and you also need to take a look at what the `field()` method does.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Leonardo is right, it checks if

- there is a post with id $post AND user_id = $user
- if yes it checks if the returned id is equal (even in type) to $post
- if yes it returns true, else false

Answer (score 0):

It's explained in the [docs](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/retrieving-your-data.html#model-field)

In your case, it retrieves the Post's `id` field and try to match with the conditions in the second parameter: `array('id' => $post, 'user_id' => $user) === $post`.

This is:

> find in the table `Posts`a row(s) with this **user** and this **post**

It will return the field in case a **match** is found, and *false* otherwise